# Docker MySQL throws CannotGetJdbcConnectionException

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat

Whenever I try to run the docker using tomcat web app, pointing to 3306 I get the following error.

```
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:391)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:440)
```

```
</pre>
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

```
</pre>
    <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
    <pre>java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

docker-compose.yml file is below

```yaml
version: "3.9" #version of docker-compose
services:
    mysql:
      container_name: mysql
      image: mysql
      ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root                    #default password of the MySQL container
        MYSQL_DATABASE: SomeDB
      volumes:
        - ./data:/var/lib/mysql                         #database data volume
        - ./src/main/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro #database files called when the container is built and started for the first time
    web:
      container_name: tomcat
      build: .
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
```

Spring servlet-context.xml is like below.

```xml
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/SomeDB?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

If I run commands through MYSQL Docker terminal, I am able to connect to the database.

mysql-connector-java maven is 8.0.33 and docker file is something like this.

```bash
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build

# Copy pom.xml to the image
COPY pom.xml /home/app/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml verify clean --fail-never

# Copy the source code 
COPY src /home/app/src
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml package

# Install Tomcat    & openjdk 8 (openjdk has java and javac)
FROM tomcat:8.5.69-jdk8-openjdk
# Copy source files to tomcat folder structure
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/someapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8090
```

Running below command shows the below ports for mysql.

`docker ps -a`

PORTS

`0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql`

Comment: The connection link is wrong, use `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/SomeDB`. Each the container has it's own hostname and `localhost` points to the app container instead

Comment: THANK you so much. After making the url change it did not work it was expected it would , with `docker-compose down --remove-orphans`, updating the url and then calling `docker-compose up -d`. So after changing the URL , What worked is calling docker prune and then calling `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @WildDev thoughts in case I would like to retain to previous url `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/SomeDB` which uses ip?  Any change that I need to make in docker file.

Comment: You also need to establish a depends on relationship from `web` to `mysql`, so docker-compose waits until `mysql` has started.

Comment: ip addresses shouldn't be used for the deployment. See the [Dockerfile example](https://github.com/WildDev/images/blob/master/Dockerfile), also consider removing `EXPOSE` statement as this is not correct

Comment: to add the dependency of mysql available with database do I need to add depends_on , mysql , service_healthy
web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy